# Attempted to upgrade CiviCRM in Drupal, crashed whole site

Tags: civicrm

CiviCRM was not working on our Drupal 7 site, so I attempted to upgrade to version 4.6. I followed https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7#
I removed the old civi files but some cache files may have lingered. Added new civi module in the tree. Went to run 
http:///civicrm/upgrade?reset=1 and the entire site is now down. What have I done wrong? How can I rectify?

Comment: more civicrm users will see this if you can repost in civicrm.stackexchange.com

Comment: and i you do i would suggest you add more info, eg what version were you upgrading from, any log errors, what happens when you run drush uli (if you use drush)